# Is there a way for my clients to access sales reports for apps I submit for them?

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play

I'm sure I'm not the first to ask but I can't find any info about this.

How can I give access to my clients to reports specifically for their apps?

I'm submitting on their behalf and wanted to get this resolved before I go further

EDIT

looking at both Apple App Store and Android Market. My goal is to grant clients access to their app sales so they can verify sales figures but obviously I don't want to give them access to other app data

Comment: There really isn't enough information in this question for anyone to give you a helpful answer. Where are the sales reports coming from? What are, "there apps"? What have you tried?

Comment: @heneryville - this has to do with Android Market.

Comment: @RafaelT - or with Apple's App Store, true.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Market doesn't allow for granting multiple users access to publisher data, let alone segmenting access. If you're using [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com), you can give insight into purchases/user behavior/etc. by granting them a Flurry account that only have access to their apps.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/). Whic gives us the analytic's information like, phone model, number of donwloads, active sessions etc. It supports blackberry,ios,android,wp7 and web apps. Give it a try. Its what we use to track apps we hand over to clients.

Comment: Thanks all, got some great advice here. Once app is submitted will try out the solutions and mark as answered the best solution. Found one here too, http://www.mopapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have a trusted 3rd party access the store data, and then prepare and distribute reports of the required subsets for the various sub-parties.

There appear to be developer web services that claim to do this.  The submitter will have to determine whether to trust them with the required access logins, and both parties will have to determine whether they trust that the data they provide is correct.

If there's enough money involved, you can hire a CPA to audit the process.

Answer (score 0):

We have the inverse problem - we developed an app that another company put into the market under their account. We have no access to the sales reports; the other company compiles figures for us. (There's a certain amount of trust involved here, of course.) Google told us that there is no support at present for anything better. Amazon AppStore isn't any better in this regard.

One thing we did as a precaution was to use a separate signing key for the apps we did with the other company than we use for apps we publish ourselves. If we ever part ways and decide to hand over the entire app to them, we can give them the signing keys without compromising our other apps.